# Telerik Tabstrip (Tabs on demand ) is not working properly

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, telerik-mvc

My Partial View contains this code:

```
   @( Html.Telerik().TabStrip()
        .Name("MeasurementScheme")
        .Items(tab =>
        {
            tab.Add()
                .Text("Weight Measure")
                .LoadContentFrom("IndexWeight", "MeasurementScheme")
                .Selected(true);




            tab.Add()
                .Text("Dimension Measure")
                .LoadContentFrom("IndexDimension", "MeasurementScheme");




        })
        )
```

But when i run my code it only displayed the partial view of first tab and when clicked on second tab it doesn't call the second one.

and one more think when i change the .selected property of second tab to true rather than first than second tab works fine and first doesn't call its view?

Ok kk This is my controller

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Web;
  using System.Web.Mvc;
  using CommerceSuite.Services;
  using CommerceSuite.Web.Models;
  using CommerceSuite.Data;
  using System.Web.Mvc.Html;
  using CommerceSuite.Web.Infrastructure;
  using CommerceSuite.Web.Models.MeasurementScheme;
  using Telerik.Web.Mvc;
  using System.Threading;
  namespace CommerceSuite.Web.Controllers
  {
      public class MeasurementSchemeController : BaseCsController
{
    private readonly IMeasurementSchemeService _measurementSchemeService;
    public MeasurementSchemeController(IMeasurementSchemeService measurementSchemeService)
    {
        this._measurementSchemeService = measurementSchemeService;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return PartialView("_Index");
    }

    // Default Partial View Page of Measure Dimension
    public ActionResult IndexDimension()
    {
        return PartialView("_IndexDimension");
    }

    // return Json List of All MeasureDimension - Method is Invoked in Index Partival View 
    [GridAction]
    public ActionResult MeasureDimensionView()
    {
        var dimensionCollection= _measurementSchemeService.GetAllMeasurementDimension().Select(x=>
            new MeasureDimensionModel()
        {
           MeasureDimensionId=x.MeasureDimensionId,
           Name=x.Name,
           Symbol = x.Symbol,
           Ratio=x.Ratio.Value,
           IsActive=x.IsActive
        });
        return Json(dimensionCollection, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public ActionResult IndexWeight()
    {
        return PartialView("_IndexWeight");
    }

    // return Json List of All MeasureDimension - Method is Invoked in Index Partival View 
    [GridAction]
    public ActionResult MeasureWeightView()
    {
        var weightCollection = _measurementSchemeService.GetAllMeasurementWeight().Select(x =>
           new MeasureWeightModel()
           {
               MeasureWeightId = x.MeasureWeightId,
               Name = x.Name,
               Symbol = x.Symbol,
               Ratio = x.Ratio.Value,
               IsActive = x.IsActive
           });
        return Json(weightCollection, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

and this is my partial view _Index.cshtml

```
        @model CommerceSuite.Web.Models.MeasurementScheme.MeasureWeightModel

       @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Measurement Information";
         Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutPartial.cshtml";

        }

      @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_Notifications.cshtml")

    <div style="margin-top: 10px; background-color:rgba(18, 149, 223, 0.35); color:#000000; text-align:center; border-bottom-style:dotted; border-top-style:dotted; border-top-width:1px; border-top-color:#aaa; border-bottom-width:1px; border-bottom-color:#aaa;">
 <h1 style="font-size: 17px; line-height:24px; font-weight:normal;">Measurement Schemes</h1>
```

```
   @section LeftOption{
<a href="#"><img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/myicons/home.png")" width="28px;" title="Home" alt="Home" /></a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="#"><img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/myicons/back.png")" width="28px;" title="Back" alt="Back" /></a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="#"><img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/myicons/forward.png")" width="28px;" title="Forward" alt="Forward" /></a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="#"><img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/myicons/refresh.png")" width="28px;" title="Refresh List" alt="Refresh" /></a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="#"><img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/myicons/search.png")" width="28px;" title="Search" alt="Search" /></a>
 }
 @section RightOption{
<a href="#" Onclick="csPopupOpen('Add Measurement Scheme','@Url.Action("Create")')"><img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/myicons/add.png")" width="28px;" title="Add New" alt="Add" /></a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="#" Onclick="csPopupOpen('Delete Measurement Scheme','@Url.Action("#")')"><img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/myicons/delete.png")" width="28px;" title="Delete" alt="Delete" /></a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="#" Onclick="csPopupOpen('Print Measurement Schemes','@Url.Action("#")')"><img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/myicons/print.png")" width="28px;" title="Print List" alt="Print" /></a>
```

}

```
     @( Html.Telerik().TabStrip()
        .Name("TabStrip")
        .Items(tab =>
        {

             tab.Add()
                .Text("Dimension Measure")
                .LoadContentFrom("IndexDimension", "MeasurementScheme")
                .Selected(true);


            tab.Add()
               .Text("Weight Measure")
               .LoadContentFrom("IndexWeight", "MeasureWeight");


        })

        )
```

and this is a partia view of measureweight _IndexDimension

```
  @model CommerceSuite.Web.Models.MeasurementScheme.MeasureDimensionModel

      @(Html.Telerik().Grid<CommerceSuite.Web.Models.MeasurementScheme.MeasureDimensionModel>()
                   .Name("MeasurementScheme")          
           .DataBinding(databinding => {
               databinding.Ajax().Select("MeasureDimensionView", "MeasurementScheme");
           })
           .Columns(columns =>
               {
                  columns.Bound(p=>p.MeasureDimensionId)
                  .ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' name='checkedRecords' value='<#= MeasureDimensionId #>' />")
                  .HeaderTemplate(
                    @<text>
                        <input type="checkbox" title="Select/Unselect All Records" id="checkAllRecords" />
                               </text>
                )
                  .Title("")
                  .Width(40)
                  .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center" });
                   columns.Bound(p => p.Name).Width(300); 
                   columns.Bound(p => p.Symbol).Width(100);
                   columns.Bound(p => p.Ratio).Width(100);
                   columns.Bound(p => p.IsActive).Width(75);
                   columns.Bound(p => p.IsActive).Title("Update").Sortable(false).Filterable(false).Width(50)
                   .ClientTemplate("<img src='../../Content/themes/myicons/edit.png' title='Edit' width='20' onclick='csPopupOpen(\"HELLO\",\"" + @Url.Action("EditDimension") + "\",<#=MeasureDimensionId #>,\"" + @Url.Action("IndexDimension") + "\")' value='Edit' > <img src='../../Content/themes/myicons/del.ico' width='20' title='delete' name='<#=MeasureDimensionId #>' onclick='csPopupOpen(\"HELLO\",\"" + @Url.Action("Delete") + "\",<#=MeasureDimensionId #>)' value='Delete' > ").Width(50);
                })
           .Pageable()
           .Scrollable()
           .Sortable()
           .Groupable()
     )
```

and this is a partial view of MeasureDimension   _IndexDimension.cshtml

```
  @model CommerceSuite.Web.Models.MeasurementScheme.MeasureDimensionModel

@(Html.Telerik().Grid<CommerceSuite.Web.Models.MeasurementScheme.MeasureDimensionModel>()
                   .Name("MeasurementScheme")          
           .DataBinding(databinding => {
               databinding.Ajax().Select("MeasureDimensionView", "MeasurementScheme");
           })
           .Columns(columns =>
               {
                  columns.Bound(p=>p.MeasureDimensionId)
                  .ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' name='checkedRecords' value='<#= MeasureDimensionId #>' />")
                  .HeaderTemplate(
                    @<text>
                        <input type="checkbox" title="Select/Unselect All Records" id="checkAllRecords" />
                               </text>
                )
                  .Title("")
                  .Width(40)
                  .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center" });
                   columns.Bound(p => p.Name).Width(300); 
                   columns.Bound(p => p.Symbol).Width(100);
                   columns.Bound(p => p.Ratio).Width(100);
                   columns.Bound(p => p.IsActive).Width(75);
                   columns.Bound(p => p.IsActive).Title("Update").Sortable(false).Filterable(false).Width(50)
                   .ClientTemplate("<img src='../../Content/themes/myicons/edit.png' title='Edit' width='20' onclick='csPopupOpen(\"HELLO\",\"" + @Url.Action("EditDimension") + "\",<#=MeasureDimensionId #>,\"" + @Url.Action("IndexDimension") + "\")' value='Edit' > <img src='../../Content/themes/myicons/del.ico' width='20' title='delete' name='<#=MeasureDimensionId #>' onclick='csPopupOpen(\"HELLO\",\"" + @Url.Action("Delete") + "\",<#=MeasureDimensionId #>)' value='Delete' > ").Width(50);
                })
           .Pageable()
           .Scrollable()
           .Sortable()
           .Groupable()
     )
```

thats all about it

Comment: Strange, could you post your controller's code and the partial views ?

Comment: Strange indeed, is there any JavaScript errors in the console?

Comment: no there is no error in the console and one more thing when i change the controller name on the second tab it works fine. or if i remove the .selected property of both and first i click on second tab than first than also it works fine in same controller but if i click on first tab than press second than it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Yeaah i found the Solutuion

I was using the same grid name in both the partial view that was the error

```
  @(Html.Telerik().Grid<ProjectName.Web.Models.MeasurementScheme.MeasureDimensionModel>()
               ***.Name("MeasurementScheme")***//This is the problem

  @(Html.Telerik().Grid<CommerceSuite.Web.Models.MeasurementScheme.MeasureDimensionModel>()
               ***.Name("MeasurementScheme")***//same as previous
```

we cant use same name of a grid.